# Implementing Android ListView With Multiple Row Layout

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a chat page (Message view).

There are images and text messages. And I am using Firebase for that.

So I tried my own code. And it's showing Images also. I mean different layout is working. But the problem is, After closing the app and then when I reopen . I am seeing links in string instead of image..

Here is my ArrayAdapter.

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<> ();
ArrayList<Integer> image = new ArrayList<> ();

Context c;
String username;
String otherusername;

ArrayList<Integer> type = new ArrayList<> ();

public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<String> message, ArrayList<Integer> image, Context c, String username, String otherusername, ArrayList<Integer> type) {
    this.message = message;
    this.image = image;
    this.c = c;
    this.username = username;
    this.otherusername = otherusername;
    this.type = type;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {

    return message.size ();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView messageView;
    CircleImageView profileImage;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return type.get (position);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    int messageType = getItemViewType (position);

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (messageType==1){
            v = View.inflate (c,R.layout.chatroom_image,null);



        }
        else {
            v = View.inflate (c, R.layout.message_item, null);



        }




    }
    if (messageType==1){
        holder = new ViewHolder ();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById (R.id.imageMessage);
        holder.profileImage = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById (R.id.profile_image);
        Picasso.with(c).load(image.get (position)).into(holder.imageView);


    }
    else {
        holder = new ViewHolder ();
        holder.messageView = (TextView) v.findViewById (R.id.message_view);
        holder.profileImage = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById (R.id.profile_image);

        holder.messageView.setText (message.get (position));
        holder.profileImage.setImageResource (image.get (position));





    }

    return v;
}
}
```

In Firebase data structure is like the following..

[image: Firebase Datastructure]

```
        messageList.setAdapter (new ChatAdapter (message_list, profile_img_list, getApplicationContext (), Fusername, chat_username,types));
```

And I am logging the data it's showing everything perfectly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please do not repost the questions you had alread asked question about "ListView With Multiple Row Layout" ... edit: obviously you should do some more research as I do not see `getViewTypeCount` nor `getItemViewType` implementation

Comment: Yes I asked. And tried doing it. But I am getting some problems with that @Selvin

Comment: Ah I am missing it. Thanx @Selvin

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `RecyclerView` instead of the old `ListView`. `ListView` is kind of deprecated really.

An example on how to use different ItemViews in `RecyclerView` is given here:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: Thank you I will try it.

Comment: Np, if you need help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

With the current implementation, you will not fill the items with data if the convert view isn't null. This will mean the list view will display the items with old data.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate view

        // populate view
    }
}
```

Try moving the code to populate the view holder outside of the null check.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate view
    }

    // always populate view
}
```